# ERROR: RuntimeError - input(): lost sys.stderr

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I finished my e-commerce project in Django and I want to deploy it in *AWS Elastic Beanstalk* and after I go some steps I faced this error `"ERROR: RuntimeError - input(): lost sys.stderr`  while initializing EB CLI repository with the eb init in the following command `eb init -p python-3.7` anyone who can help me, please?